# How can I display a waiting progress bar before the application started on an IPhone

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, progress-bar

It takes a long to start up the application I write on an iPhone. I hope to display a waiting progress bar to indicate the percentage of the startup progress. Can anyone help me? I am new to the Development of IOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. 
The application needs to be started before you can show any dynamic content.
After your first ViewController is loaded you can of course show a progress bar and do loading.
Before that, you can only show a static image Default.png & Default@2x.png.
If you delay the heavy loading to after your `-[ViewController viewDidLoad]`-method is finished you can show any kind of GUI while doing the heavy work.

Edit:
This example will detach a new thread in your viewDidLoad and do some heavy work (in this case sleep for 1 second) and update a `UIProgressView` and log the progress as it sleeps 10 times, incrementing the progressview with 0.1 each time.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 // .....
   [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(workerBee) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}

- (void)workerBee
{
    NSAutoreleasePool* workerPool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    // Put your image loading between this line and [workerpool release]

    for (float i = 0; i<1; i+= 0.1)
    {
        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(updateProgress:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:i]];
        sleep(1000);
    }
    [workerPool release];
}

- (void)updateProgress:(NSNumber*)number
{
    NSLog("Progress is now: %@", number);
    [progressView setProgress:[number floatValue]];
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason that we chose to do the progress bar as the background thread rather than the sleep/heavy work? I would've guessed it would be better the other way around

Answer (score 0):

Place a loading bar in the first screen and start your computation-heavy code in another thread after displaying it.

Comment: What is the first screen? Do I initialize it in the viewDidLoad mot hod?

Comment: The first screen is the one that is added as a subview of the `UIWindow` in the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method in you app delegate. For the rest you can check @sveinungkb's answer.

Comment: I use the launch image feature to show a static image Default.png. Can I place the the loading bar in the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method ? I try, but I can not see the bar? How could I change it to the top over the static default image?

Comment: You can only change the launch image, you can't add anything else. In the `application...` method you have to add the progress bar as a subview of the first view you display.

Comment: Create a viewcontroller with an UIImageView (set your Default.png as image) as background and an UIProgressView on top. The user will then briefly see Default.png and then Default.png with a progress bar on top which you can update as you load your images (see my example in the answer above).