# a simple "Wait" animation in ios 5 on a viewcontroller

Tags: ios

I have a simple ViewController with 5 labels each of which get populated with data dynamically on runtime as a result of regex parsing. I want to show any simple "Wait" animation, while the labels are getting their data, to tell users that processing is taking place.

I read a lot of SO solutions which more or less try to do something similar but I am nt able to get the simplest of working code.

To start with I dont need how much % of work is done i.e. no progress bar. Just Wait is enough. Later on may be i would want to add that logic bt I need a start right now!

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9902496/how-can-i-display-a-waiting-progress-bar-before-the-application-started-on-an-ip) should have worked but it doesnt :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding [UIActivityIndicatorView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActivityIndicatorView_Class/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView.html)??

Comment: Not only is UIActivityIndicatorView easy to use, it's also standard -- users will know exactly what it means as soon as they see it.

Comment: where should i put the code (creating the activityIndicator view and start animation) if i want the animation to start showing when a user presses a button in the navigation controller heade?. i tried putting it in prepareforsegue but it did not work.

Comment: use [yourUIActivityIndicatorView startAnimating] on buttonpress and then [yourUIActivityIndicatorView stopAnimating] when done.

Answer (score 0):

Very nice loading indicator project ... https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD

If you need something simple than previous answer about the UIActivityIndicator is correct